# Which files needs to be deployed from a Dart project?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have an AngularJS project that I am thinking of migrating to Dart. I do not want to migrate the whole project in a big-bang, so I am looking for ways to run the two apps side-by-side.

The dart app will run on the root as index.html. The js app will run on a separate path, say '/jsApp'.

When I build a test project, it seems that the /build directory includes a lot of unnecessary files. Would I need to deploy the complete contents of the /build/web directory?

What is it that actually gets loaded? Do html files still get loaded at runtime or are they bundled into the main file?

Do I need main.dart.js as well as main.dart.precompiled.js? It seems that they are very large files for a trivial app. Is that to be expected?

It is still unclear to me how all these things hang together.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the generated files as small as possible, you should:

- Make sure your pubspec.yaml includes the angular transformer, as explained here: [Angulardart. Creating your first app](https://angulardart.org/tutorial/03-ch01-creating-your-first-app.html)

Your pubspec.yaml should look like this:

```
name: angular_dart_demo
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  angular: 0.12.0
  [...]
transformers:
-  angular
  html_files:
    - web/my_html_template.html
    - web/another_html_template.html
```

- Build from the command line with pub build

This way you will get 800KB js, instead of 5MB js ;)
That's because Angular Dart uses *mirrors* and, as a result, the generated js code can get very big if you don't use the angular transformer.

I think html templates are copied to the build directory and will be requested at runtime.

You will have to merge the contents you get from "pub build" with your existing js application somehow.

Comment: shadow_dom is deprecated (will lead to a lot of errors when built to JS) you should use web_components instead.

Comment: You are right, Günter. I will remove it from my answer. Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 1):

I am using AngularJS with Dart controllers mixed in.  You do not have to adapt your current project structure to use the pub build.  Just use dart2js to compile the individual dart files and include the ".js" files in your page.  You do not have to add the native dart script tag or include the dart bootstrap in your code.  Just include a script tag for the generated js file (the only file you need) and it will do what you expect.  I plan to write up a brief overview of this soon.

Comment: I guess this doesn't work with static injector which provides huge performance advantages. Static injector needs to run the di transformer (usually invoked by `pub build` - but can be run manually too)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the entire build directory needs to be deployed and there are normally no unnecessary files. 
The `*.precompiled.js` files are not generated anymore in recent Dart builds (this was for CSP compliance).

What Dart version are you using?

If you build in debug mode also the source map files are generated in the build directory.

The browser loads the HTML file the user requests and then loads the script files references in `<script>` tags in this HTML and all other resources (img, css, ...)

I don't know if the build output of an Angular component with an external HTML-template file is inlined in the `index.html` or if they are copied as they are.

Comment: I am (now) using Dart 1.4.2_r36647, which I got from the download site today. It is still generating a 'precompiled' file. The 'main.dart.js' file is still over a megabyte for little more than 'Hello World'. Is that normal? I thought I saw Misko say somewhere that they had got the generated file size down to 200KB.

Comment: I guess, when you run `pub build` form DartEditor it is run in `debug mode` which generates bigger output (no minification, ...). Can you try to run `pub build` from the console? if it still doesn't produce the expected output try `pub build --mode=release`